# Cucumber tags not applied, all scenarios are run

Tags: cucumber

In the below case, I want only scenarios with tags - `@smoke` should be run, however it runs all the scenarios. Tags is not applied when I run this:

```
test runner class
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)    
@CucumberOptions(
features= {"src/test/java/myfeatures"},
glue= {"stepdefinition"},
plugin= {"pretty"},
monochrome=true,
tags= "@smoke",
dryRun=false

            )

Feature: Laptop search

@smoke
Scenario: simple data passing

Given I have a search field on the amazon page
When i search for the product "ssss" and price 555
Then product name with "sss" is displayed

Scenario: simple data passing

Given I have a search field on the amazon page
When i search for the product "a" and price 22
Then product name with "a" is displayed

Scenario: simple data passing

Given I have a search field on the amazon page
When i search for the product "b" and price 33
Then product name with "b" is displayed
```

Comment: Do you execute the runner class or the feature file?

Comment: ITs from the runner class

Comment: Then I don't see anything wrong. You may have environment variables or properties set with other tag filters. If you put a breakpoint in `Cucumber.class` you can debug the code. It's not terribly difficult to follow.

Comment: Could it relate to the same name of scenarios? If I remember well, it could cause issues in older versions of Cucumber, isn't it?

Comment: if i run the runnerfile as junit, it runs only the tagged scenarios, however if i run the runner file by right click new configuration->select feature file and run, it runs all the tags

Answer (score 0):

You're using IDEA to run your features directly. So IDEA uses Cucumbers CLI, not your runner class.

You can edit the run configuration in IDEA and add the `--tags @smoke` option.

For other options use the `--help` option.